# Is it possible can we performed performance testing of IVR application Using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have IVR application Can anyone tell me how to performed Performance Testing using jmeter or suggest any other tool that supports.

Comment: hello, what is IVR ? At least a link would help in your question. Could you give more details on how IVR works ? What did you try on your side ? thx

Comment: Interactive voice response (IVR) are automated telephony systems that interact with callers, gathers information, and routes calls to the appropriate recipient.

Comment: @BhargavRao, may I know the reason behind deletion of my answer? I am neither a representative of the product nor promoting the tool. As user asked, I am suggesting him one of the available tools that I am aware of. If this is not allowed, how can he get to know that the tool is even present! By the way, I never used the tool and it is my friend who is using it for performance testing of the IVR application.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter can help you only in the situation when there is a [backend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends) which does the voice recognition and the voice in some form is being sent to this backend for parsing and converting into text.

If this is the case you can capture the requests using JMeter's built in HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder or alternative solutions like [Badboy](http://www.badboy.com.au/bbnews.html) or [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-) and replay them with increased number of users to get the associated metrics and determine the maximum throughput of the backend.